# Contrast Fluids in MRI: Which tissues "glow" first?

Tags: metabolism, cancer, mri

I am a bioinformatic and data scientist in progress, working on my Master Thesis about prostate cancer. Now I am at that point, I have a strong guessing, that contrast fluids in magnetic resonance images (of the prostate region) will first show their effect in blood vessels, and later in other tissues by a specific ranking/order/timing. But I can not find any good (scientific) source to flesh out this hypothesis.

I found some equations about relaxation times, but this seem to be more about "wavelength" then "when after injection will it start". Also I found a lot of equations for different transportation between cells and from blood to cell. But this is to specific.

My wish would be some kind of table, stating "*after injection of contrast fluid, first blood vessels will be visible, then tissues nearby, then tissues with very active metabolism (like cancer), then tissues without fat, then tissues with i do not know...*"

**In which scientific source I can find some characteristics, in which order (in question of time) contrast fluid is transported into tissues in the prostate region?**

Edit: In case it is as simple as the comments state, that I may need other terms for search, for example I tried: "tissue fluid transport"; "contrast fluid which tissue gets it first"; "how fast react tissues to contrast fluid"; "relaxation rate of different tissues" and combinations, more and less words, and so on.

Comment: This is possibly interesting, but I was readily able to find some relevant references  by googling ('"contrast fluid" penetration prostate'), e.g. table 1 [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6175214/). I'd suggest putting a little more effort into your search.

Comment: @MaximilianPress Thank you! I did not have "penetration" as term in my search. Sometimes it is that simple, with the right words :) (I do not know, if this is because I am not full biologist, or not native english...) Would you make an answer out of it?

Comment: @MaximilianPress I had a closer look into this source, and it is not helpful for me. The times noted in the table are connected with the different contrast fluids and their different dosage. And it gives times for "when is the structure (ie whole liver, whole prostate gland) completely visible". I also tried the search term you suggested, and your link was the only one, matching in general my goals. The other results are about prostate infections or general health of male organs.

Comment: This isn't really my field, but I think you're not finding anything because what you're describing isn't how contrast is used. Contrast is used to differentiate tissues at a single point in time, it's not as if things light up one after another. You might look at search terms like "time course gadolinium" to find information about when certain tissue contrasts are most prominent, but that's not going to be because some tissue "got it first", these are smooth differential equations.

Comment: @BryanKrause Thank you for the help in search terms. I have a time series of MR images, so it is not one single point in time in my case.